# Native rotation for dx-input

Tags: angular, input, rotation, devextreme

I'm using devExtreme to use some input with min & max. Here's my code :

```
<dx-slider [min]="0" [max]="100" [value]="data.value"></dx-slider>
```

My questions are those :

1) Is there a way to rotate vertically this input? Maybe with a `rotation` property?

2) Is there a way to stop the event when i "slide" up & down this element?

I've tried rotatating the component with css in this way :

```
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

but the result is that the input is correctly rotate by 90 deg, but instead of goind "up and down" with the scroll to change the value, I have to go from left to right (obviously), so I wanted, in case there is no way to native rotate this component, to stop the event and replace somehow with a my custom event.

Thank you in advice.

Jacopo.

Answer (score 0):

[Devexpress official answer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T555065/how-to-make-dxslider-vertical)

*dxSlider is rendered as several nested elements and each of them uses its own style that is used for the slider functionality. So, the use of the CSS transform attribute is not enough to rotate dxSlider since this attribute does not influence the functionality. I am afraid dxSlider does not provide a way to rotate its content.*